# What will be the BROKER_CLIENT_URL for Snyk broker setup for gitlab private instance

Tags: gitlab, devops, snyk

I am trying to setup Snyk broker for gitlab private instance and broker should run in docker container.
docker run --restart=always 
-p 8000:8000 
-e BROKER_TOKEN=secret-broker-token 
-e GITLAB_TOKEN=secret-gitlab-token 
-e GITLAB=your.gitlab.domain.com 
-e BROKER_CLIENT_URL=http://my.broker.client:8000 
-e PORT=8000 
snyk/broker:gitlab

Here what will be the BROKER_CLIENT_URL

Comment: It should be the URL for your [snyk broker client](https://docs.snyk.io/features/integrations/snyk-broker/broker-introduction). I.E., the scheme/hostname/port that will be used to reach the container you are about to run.

Comment: Ok if it is on a private subnet and think the ip is 10.0.4.12 then the url will be http://10.0.4.12:8000 right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BROKER_CLIENT_URL` is important for webhooks, so it needs to be reachable from your Gitlab instance. It would generally be the IP address or FQDN of your Broker container.